# Finding the moment of inertia through superposition?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

Let's say I have a body consisting of two homogenous spheres/balls that touch each other. I also have a body-fixed coordinate system which consists of that body's principal axes. I know the moment of inertia for each of the spheres alone is $I=\frac{2}{5}mR^2$. Can I use that to find the moment of inertia of the entire body?

I need this because for such a body, with such a coordinate system, I don't think integration would be very simple...

I'm looking for all three moments of inertia, however two of them should be the same because of rotational symmetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the axis passing two centers:  $I=\frac{2}{5}mR^2+\frac{2}{5}mR^2$.

About each of two axes perpendicular to each other and the previous one passing through the contact point: $I=\frac{2}{5}mR^2+mR^2+\frac{2}{5}mR^2+mR^2$  (using parallel axes theorem).